# Spring Batch JpaTransactionManager will affect Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch, transactionmanager

If I override and use `JpaTransactionManager` with `Spring Batch` will it affect `Spring Data JPA`? What is the difference between `Spring Batch Transaction Manager` vs `Spring Data JPA`? Is there any connection between them? And If I use the following transaction manager bean will it affect Spring Data JPA repositories and CRUD operations in any way I mean a bad way?

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dts;

@Bean
@Primary
@Override
public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager jpa = new JpaTransactionManager();
    jpa.setDataSource(dts);
    return jpa;
}
```

Comment: Interesting question. I have to ask if you gave it a go. Did you try to run some queries to see if the behavior change in any way? I'm not sure why you had to override it

Comment: Actually I have to override it because I am using JPA CRUD operation inside batch process. So If I didn't specify `JpaTransactionManager` the `save` is not working and it is throwing an error no transaction was provided... because it is default using `DatasourceTransactionManager`.

Comment: What if you try to add an @Transactional annotation in your save method?

Comment: @MatheusR I haven't tried it. I will try and let you know. Thank you.